# Access quick link information through API

Tags: branch.io

I've created several personalized quick links using the branch.io Dashboard - and I'd like to implement a simple portal where users can see their personalized URL, copy it so they can share it on social media, and also show a simple 'referral' counter so they can track the number of users they've referred. Since the links were created by me using the dashboard and not through the SDK, I can't seem to find a way to access that information (I need to see clicks/installs per custom URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Branch referral program you can get information on referrals and associate referring and referred users. Refer these links for more details:

https://docs.branch.io/viral/referrals/

https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/#referral

You can use Branch webhooks to export data to your server. You simply need to specify a URL for the POST or GET requests.

After importing this data into your internal systems you can do analysis and create a personalised URL for each user.

You can refer to this document for more details:
https://docs.branch.io/exports/ua-webhooks/#overview